# What is better for battery_changed? broadcast receivers, or service, or intentService?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I want my app to know battery percentage change if the phone is charging.

So I used `BroadcastReceiver` with `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` to register another `BroadcastReceiver` with `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` when the phone is charging, and then I thought "wouldn't it be better if I used `Service`?"

Then I searched about `Service`, and I saw `IntentService`, so now I wonder what is better for `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`, and what is better for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`?

I think I should use `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`, and `IntentService` for  `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, am I wrong?

I want `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` to run always and forever(except if I found a better way), and run `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` when the phone is charging.

Comment: Broadcast receivers are always better to listen for system changes

Comment: You cannot register receivers in the manifest for most implicit broadcasts on Android 8 and newer [due to background execution limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BroadcastReceivers and service are two different things

Broadcast receivers are designed to listen to some events and perform action on it while services are used to do some task in background(without activity) like playing music in background service

Intent service is designed on top of service for long running tasks that are to be performed on a separate thread

In your scenario the best answer would be to use a broadcast receiver. It will be called everytime and there is no need to shut it down after you have performed your task unlike services